# How to suppress Android D8 build warnings

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.2, android-d8

I recently upgraded to Android Studio 3.2 which enables D8 Desugaring by default. In the build logs, i see lot of warnings related to D8. Could any one guide me on how to suppress these warnings?

> D8: Interface `java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer` not found.
>   It's needed to make sure desugari ng of
>   `org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_8ff85ea.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime$1`
>   is correct. Desugaring will assume that this interface has no default
>   method.
>
> D8: Interface `java.awt.event.ActionListener` not found. It's needed
>   to make sure desugaring of `edu.u md.cs.findbugs.gui2.MainFrameMenu$2`
>   is correct. Desugaring will assume that this interface has no default
>   method.

Comment: This link might help- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52783212/how-to-resolve-multiple-d8-warnings-class-x-was-not-found-it-is-required-for